# How to json dump a dict with foreign characters

Tags: python, json, unicode

To print a dictionary I usually do:

```
def print_row(self):
    print(json.dumps(self.example_entry, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

However, here is what I now get:

```
>>> f.print_row()
{
    "#export_date": "1475226000146",
    "artist_id": "1159638168",
    "artist_type_id": "1",
    "is_actual_artist": "1",
    "name": "\uc2e4\ubc84 \ud14c\uc774\ube14",
    "view_url": "http://itunes.apple.com/artist/silbeo-teibeul/id1159638168?uo=5"
}
```

How would I get the `name` field printed as it would print in the dict, such as:

```
>>> print(f.example_entry)
{'#export_date': '1475226000146', 'artist_id': '1159638168', 'name': '실버 테이블', 'is_actual_artist': '1', 'view_url': 'http://itunes.apple.com/artist/silbeo-teibeul/id1159638168?uo=5', 'artist_type_id': '1'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False)

{
    "#export_date": "1475226000146",
    "artist_id": "1159638168",
    "artist_type_id": "1",
    "is_actual_artist": "1",
    "name": "실버 테이블",
    "view_url": "http://itunes.apple.com/artist/silbeo-teibeul/id1159638168?uo=5"
}
```