# Python3 chinese character into json

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-2.x

I have a problem when i try to create a json file. the json file is created but the value is not good. The inside of value is a chinese charater, in python the chinese character is working, it is displayed. But, when i try to save the values into json. the chinese character become `\u3010\u725b\u8089\u9762\u3011\u5b83`. and also the value is list of dictionary `[{}]`. i was try like this :

```
text = '[{"one":"\u3010\u725b\u8089\u9762\u3011\u5b83"}]'
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
   json.dump(text, f)
```

And the result, still like `[{"one":"\u3010\u725b\u8089\u9762\u3011\u5b83"}]`

and i was try some code like :

```
json.dumps(json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
decode("utf-8")
encoding='utf-8'
```

And also, i was try the another solution from [How to json dump a dict with foreign characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878762/how-to-json-dump-a-dict-with-foreign-characters). The result is :

```
>>> text_baru = {
...     "#export_date": "1475226000146",
...     "artist_id": "1159638168",
...     "artist_type_id": "1",
...     "is_actual_artist": "1",
...     "name": "\uc2e4\ubc84 \ud14c\uc774\ube14",
...     "view_url": "http://itunes.apple.com/artist/silbeo-teibeul/id1159638168?uo=5"
... }
>>> json.dumps(text_baru, ensure_ascii=False)
'{"#export_date": "1475226000146", "name": "\\\\uc2e4\\\\ubc84 \\\\ud14c\\\\uc774\\\\ube14", "view_url": "http://itunes.apple.com/artist/silbeo-teibeul/id1159638168?uo=5", "artist_type_id": "1", "is_actual_artist": "1", "artist_id": "1159638168"}'
```

still not working

Comment: I already try that solution. But not working for me. I edited my results in my question when i try that solution.

Comment: Set the encoding of the file that you are trying to write to `utf-8`. By default encoding will be set to the value return by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`.

Comment: @StefaniJohnsson  Upgrade to Python 3.  You are seeing the result on Python 2.x.

Comment: @wim actually, i already using python3

Comment: Are you aware that `[{"one":"\u3010\u725b\u8089\u9762\u3011\u5b83"}]` is perfectly valid JSON? But if you definitely need/want to see literal Chinese characters in the output, the `ensure_ascii` parameter is what you want. If it doesn't work, then you have to debug, start with the input. For example, try `"name": u"\uc2e4..."` in the last example (ie. with an explicit `u"..."` prefix, works for both Python 2 and 3).

Comment: In the first example, `text` is a string. If the single quotes are removed, it will work as expected: `json.dumps(text, ensure_ascii=False)` -> `'[{"one": "【牛肉面】它"}]'`. Of course, your terminal must have the necessary unicode support for all the characters to be displayed correctly.